# Как работают массивы в Си?

Tags: c, массивы, инициализация

**Код:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[10];
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("arr[%d] = %d;\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Вывод:**

```
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 0;
arr[3] = 0;
arr[4] = 4195632;
arr[5] = 0;
arr[6] = 4195344;
arr[7] = 0;
arr[8] = -669909312;
arr[9] = 32765;
```

Чем обуславливается значение, которое выводится на экран?

Comment: Тем что массив после создания ничем не инициализируется (не обнуляется). Пока вы в него ничего не запишите, там могут быть любые значения ("мусор").

Comment: Пожалуйста, поменяйте заголовок вопроса на более подходящий - ваш вопрос никак не связан с "работой массивов"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вы создали в блоке функции `main` локальный массив с автоматической продолжительностью памяти (automatic storage duration).

```
int main(void) {
    int arr[10];
```

Такие массивы не инициализируются неявно, и их элементы имеют неопределенные значения, что и демонстрирует вывод вышей программы.

Согласно стандарту C (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 10 **If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate.** If an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
>   unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively)
>   according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized
>   (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized
>   to zero bits;

Вы могли бы инициализировать массив нулями при его объявлении

```
int main(void) {
    int arr[10] = { 0 };
```

Или вы могли бы сразу же инициализировать первый элемент массива числом 1,  второй - 2, а остальные - нулями.

```
int main(void) {
    int arr[10] = { 1, 2 };
```

Или же вы могли бы объявить массив со статической продолжительностью памяти. В этом случае компилятор неявно инициализировал бы его нулями. Например

```
int main(void) {
    static int arr[10];
```

или

```
int arr[10];
int main(void) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к массивам и тому, как они работают. И слово "обуславливаются" в данном случае не применимо. Эти значения не обусловлены.

Вы обращаетесь к неинициализированным объектам. Тот факт, что эти объекты являются элементами массива никакой роли не играет. Неинициализированные объекты содержат *неопределенные значения* (indeterminate value), которые в языке С могут оказаться либо некими *неспецифицированными значениями* (unspecified value), либо "запрещенными" представлениями (trap representation).

> **3.19.2**
>   **indeterminate value**
>   either an unspecified value or a trap representation

В случае, если вы наткнетесь на запрещенное представление, ваша программа будет иметь неопределенное поведение. (Тип `int` на вашей платформе скорее всего не имеет запрещенных представлений.)

В случае неспецифицированного значения язык не гарантирует вам, что это значение является *стабильным*, т.е. повторные обращения к одному и тому же неинициализированному объекту могут видеть в нем разные значения.

Другими словами, эти значения не "обусловлены" вообще: ни изначально при объявлении объекта, ни с ходом времени при последующих обращениях к объекту.

Comment: Именно это мне и непонятно: как из ничего выходит что-то?